# Calculating feedback factor \$V_f/I_o\$

Tags: circuit-analysis, feedback

I'm unsure how to calcuate the feedback factor here. It's a voltage / current, so it's a resistor value, but what do you do when the values aren't from the same source? ie. it's \$V_f\$ and \$I_o\$

Here's the diagram:

[image: diagram]

When you turn off \$I_f\$, what actually happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the circuit is drawn, there are two contributions to the voltage \$V_f\$:

\$V_f = I_f \cdot Z_{11} + I_o \cdot Z_{12}\$

Thus, to find \$Z_{12}\$, you must *zero* \$I_f\$.

> When you turn off \$I_f\$, what actually happens?

What actually happens is that port 1 is open-circuited.

Conceptually, a voltmeter is connected to port 1 and a current is driven into port 2.  The measured voltage is then just the product of that current and \$Z_{12}\$.

For this circuit, the calculation is almost trivial and \$Z_{12}\$ can be written by inspection.

---

> Do you mind showing how to calculate this?

Find the current through \$R_2\$ (think *current division*) and then, using Ohm's Law, find the voltage across.  This voltage is just \$V_f\$ due to \$I_o\$.  If you set \$I_o = 1A\$, then the numeric value of \$V_f\$ equals the numeric value of \$Z_{12}\$

Comment: > the calculation is almost trivial and Z12 can be written by inspection.

That's the part I'm having trouble with. If it was the voltage and current from Vf/If (short circuiting the otherside), you simply calculate the resistance seen by \$V_f\$ (ie. (R1 + R3) || R2). 

Do you mind showing how to calculate this?

Comment: @tgun926, see update to my answer.  You should be able to take it from there.